# Filling in the blanks with time series summary data

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, time-series

I'm trying to draw a simple (read: fast) sparkline for "data received from a sensor every *n* minutes"

The data is very simple, it's one, or more readings for a given timestamp, identified by the sensor's mac address:

```
# SELECT mac, ants, read_at FROM normalized_readings LIMIT 10;
        mac        | ants |         read_at
-------------------+------+-------------------------
 f0:d1:a9:a0:fe:e7 |  -87 | 2013-07-14 09:25:15.215
 74:de:2b:fa:ca:cf |  -69 | 2013-07-14 09:25:14.81
 74:de:2b:fa:ca:cf |  -69 | 2013-07-14 09:25:14.81
 74:de:2b:fa:ca:cf |  -69 | 2013-07-14 09:25:15.247
 38:aa:3c:8f:a0:4f |  -85 | 2013-07-14 09:25:21.672
 38:aa:3c:8f:a0:4f |  -87 | 2013-07-14 09:25:21.695
 60:67:20:c8:bc:80 |  -83 | 2013-07-14 09:25:26.73
 60:67:20:c8:bc:80 |  -81 | 2013-07-14 09:25:26.737
 f0:d1:a9:a0:fe:e7 |  -83 | 2013-07-14 09:25:36.207
 f0:d1:a9:a0:fe:e7 |  -91 | 2013-07-14 09:26:07.77
(10 rows)
```

I'm trying to come up with something like:

```
# SELECT 
    mac, date_trunc('minute', read_at) AS minute, COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
    normalized_readings
  GROUP BY mac, minute LIMIT 10;
        mac        |       minute        | count
-------------------+---------------------+-------
 00:08:ca:e6:a1:86 | 2013-07-14 16:22:00 |     6
 00:10:20:56:7c:e2 | 2013-07-27 05:29:00 |     1
 00:21:5c:1c:df:7d | 2013-07-14 09:44:00 |     1
 00:21:5c:1c:df:7d | 2013-07-14 09:46:00 |     1
 00:21:5c:1c:df:7d | 2013-07-14 09:48:00 |     1
 00:24:d7:b3:31:04 | 2013-07-15 06:51:00 |     1
 00:24:d7:b3:31:04 | 2013-07-15 06:53:00 |     3
 00:24:d7:b3:31:04 | 2013-07-15 06:59:00 |     3
 00:24:d7:b3:31:04 | 2013-07-15 07:02:00 |     3
 00:24:d7:b3:31:04 | 2013-07-15 07:06:00 |     3
(10 rows)
```

**But notice all the empty periods, I'd like to be able to extract `0` for those time periods to indicate that the sensors weren't recording data.**

Probably I'll only ever want to show the last 12/24 hours worth of data, so I suppose I could brute-force this by selecting artificial dates from `NOW()` 12/24 hours into the past, and for each *resolution* (probably 1, or 5 minutes), I'd have to query the readings table, and SUM the number of readings, but this sounds horrible inefficient.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without brute-forcing things? As far as I can see, when I'm grouping by selecting minutes, I'm automatically coming at this from the wrong side?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of query, you want a driver table that generates all the combinations of "macs" and "minutes".  Postgres has the nice function `generate_series()` to get a counter for each minute.

So, the idea is to start with all the macs and generate a series for each minute.  Then use `left outer join` from the driver table to get a row for each value.

```
with t as (
      SELECT mac, date_trunc('minute', read_at) AS minute, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM normalized_readings
      GROUP BY mac, minute
      LIMIT 10
     )
select driver.mac, driver.minute, coalesce(cnt, 0)
from (select mac, minminute,
             minminute + cast(cast(generate_series(0,
                                                   cast(extract(epoch from maxminute - minminute)/60 as int)
                                                  ) as character varying
                                  )||' minute' as interval
                             ) as minute
      from (select mac, min(minute) as minminute, max(minute) as maxminute
            from t
            group by mac
           ) macs
     ) driver left outer join
     t
     on t.mac = driver.mac and
        t.minute = driver.minute
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a95ff/2).

The only issue that I can see is how you get your original data -- the definition of `t`.  I followed the example in the question.  But, it doesn't actually make sense.  You have a `limit` with no `order by`.  You should put in the appropriate `order by`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, they should be ordered by `mac, read_at` probably. I threw in an arbitrary `LIMIT 10` in order not to kill SO with half a million entries, but you're right. `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` doesn't make sense, really.